# Twilio Repeat SAY

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

When utilizing  and  TwiML, how can I setup a repeating loop?

My use case is calling a support line, Twilio waiting through on hold music until a tech answers call and dials 1. I can't figure how to wait for human to pickup so I figure repeat forever until pickup. If I can figure out repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `loop` attribute with a value of 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Say loop="0">Hello World</Say>
</Response>
```

> The 'loop' attribute specifies how many times you'd like the text
>   repeated. The default is 1. Specifying '0' will cause the 
>   verb to loop until the call is hung up.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say#attributes-voice

.

or if you are playing an audio file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="0">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

> The 'loop' attribute specifies how many times the audio file is
>   played. The default behavior is to play the audio once. Specifying '0'
>   will cause the  verb to loop until the call is hung up.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes

Comment: Is there a way to just loop it couple of times? Trying this was returning an error (503).

Comment: @ZZzzZZzz `loop="2"` should loop two times. I don't think the error comes from the number of loops. Maybe ask a question and post your code. You're probably not returning valid XML.